# Will JSP converted as a servlet code if i use spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using JSP as a view resolver in spring-mvc. Will those pages be converted to servlets in tomcat?

If so, is the same applicable for other views like Velocity, Thymeleaf etc.? Please explain how it works.

Comment: jsp always converts to servlet, not sure about the rest

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a JSP is always converted to a servlet, that is how JSP files work.

The same is not always true in other view/templates engine. For example, Velocity is a Java-based template engine, velocity templates are parsed, but it does not depend on having a servlet engine.

Regarding to Spring, it has view resolvers for a lot of different technologies, so you have a layer of abstraction and don't have to worry about how the views are internally translated to render your model.

Answer (score 2):

> Will JSP converted as a servlet code if i use spring?

Yes. If you use JSP anywhere* it will be converted to Servlet.

```
* - For Java EE Applications which uses Servlet containers.
```

I don't about `Velocity ,thymleaf,etc.`.

Answer (score 1):

JSP, Velocity, Freemarker etc. in respect to Spring MVC are template libraries. For example, the user make an HTTP request to a specified URL. This URL is mapped to a Spring controller. The controller will build an instance of a model and return the view and the model. Then Spring will use the view (i.e. a jsp file) and convert it to HTML using the model. The user gets the resulting HTML.

More about Spring MVC and templates here
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/view.html

Comment: If other templates are not converted as servlet then it's better to use  always template engine like velocity and team viewer right?

Comment: I'm not following the "converted as servlet"? They are just templates for HTML. Spring transforms the templates into HTML. Your users shouldn't be navigating to the jsp file itself. In fact, its good practice to put the template files (jsp files) under the WEB-INF directory so they can not be navigated to and force the users to go through your controllers.

Comment: It's not correct to say "Spring transforms the templates into HTML". Rather, Spring calls into the template engine so the chosen template engine can do it's work. For a JSP, this delegation is going to involve calling `RequestDispatcher.forward()` or `RequestDispatcher.include()` (depending on configuration), which calls into the servlet generated by the servlet engine from compiling the JSP.

Comment: That's fine my concern is ,if i use JSP with JSTL the tag libraries are more enough to read object from model and i can put into to HTML node and i can render the view. So why its needs to be converted into a servlet if its JSP template or my understanding is wrong

Comment: @VijayM it needs to be converted into a Servlet class because *that is how JSP files work*. Spring needs to call into something to build the HTML, and there is no engine that interprets the JSP contents as is - the way this works with JSP is for the JSP compiler to compile it into a Java class that extends `Servlet`. Note though that this does not mean that the generated Servlet is publically available to your users - just because it is a servlet class does not mean people can access it directly.

Comment: @Mattb "Spring calls into the template engine so the chosen template engine can do it's work"- I am happy with this answer. i have one more doubt if i have JSP any way its going to convert into servlet or if  i have template engine it reads the model object and render the page as it is. So performance wise which will be good.(but development wise using template engine will be pretty much faster)

Comment: @VijayM I'm not sure if I understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Mattb I mean to say if i use JSP anyway it needs to be converted as as a Servlet,but template engine will never be converted as a servlet. So performance wise using template engine will be better right?

Comment: Performance may be better but depending on what you are doing it may be negligible. Development wise, our group prefers template frameworks like Freemarker. For one, it forces us to keep business logic out of the view. With JSP business logic tends to creep in making it difficult decouple later.

Comment: @VijayM compilation into a servlet class is a onetime cost. Template engines typically need to load and parse the template into some sort of in-memory data structure as well.